# How to print full pyramid of asterisk in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to print full pyramid of '*' in Powershell but getting strange output. I am attaching my code,erratic output and expected output.

```
Clear-Host;
Write-Verbose -Message "Program to print Full Pyramid of *" -Verbose;
[int]$limit = Read-Host "Enter the number of rows";


Write-Host "Below is the full pyramid:" -ForegroundColor Green;
Write-Host " ";
for (($i = 1),($k = 1); $i -le $limit; $i++) {
    <#The for loop is for calculating spaces#>
    for ($space = 1; $space -le ($limit - $i); $space++) {
        Write-Host " " -NoNewline;
    }
    <#The while loop is used for printing * #>
    while ($k -le ((2*$i) -1)) {
        Write-Host " * " -NoNewline;
        $k++;
    }
    Write-Host " `n ";
}
```

```
OUTPUT I am getting:-
-------------------------------------------------------------------
VERBOSE: Program to print Full Pyramid of *
Enter the number of rows: 5
Below is the full pyramid:
 
     *  
 
    *  *  
 
   *  *  
 
  *  *  
 
 *  *
```

```
Expected Output:-
---------------------------------------
        *
      * * *
    * * * * *
  * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
```

I am expecting a full pyramid of '*'. The while loop is the one that prints the '*'.

Comment: Without going much into it, wouldn't you need to reset `$k`? Otherwise, how else would it print the correct # of asterisks for the next row?